# ndk Build command failed Error while executing process

Tags: android, android-studio, build, android-ndk, telegram

I cloned the latest code from the github.com/DrKLO/Telegram
When i try to run it in Android Studio i get the following error:
I did not check if the path is correct, as i did a clean clone and did not change anything in the code just yet, so i guess that's not the problem. I'd be really grateful if someone could help me with this really urgend issue.

```
    Build command failed.
        Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

    Build command failed.

    Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afat\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/armv7_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\armv7_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afat\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64_SDK23/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64_SDK23\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64_SDK23/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64_SDK23\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-23 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64_SDK23/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64_SDK23\debug\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/afat/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\afat\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x86/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x86\release\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/x64/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\x64\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File


Build command failed.


Error while executing process F:\SDK\AndroidSDK\sdk\ndk-bundle\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-21 NDK_OUT=C:/Users/Boy/AndroidStudioProjects/Telegram/TMessagesProj/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/arm64/foss/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=C:\Users\Boy\AndroidStudioProjects\Telegram\TMessagesProj\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\arm64\foss\lib NDK_APPLICATION_MK:=jni/Application.mk APP_PLATFORM:=android-16 -j8 APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}


process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.


*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you what to do:

> *** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.